# How to record/inspect bluetooth traffic of a macOS app

Tags: macos, bluetooth

I'm running a certain app on macOS 10.13, that communicates with a bluetooth device. I want to inspect the packets that are being exchanged. How can I do that?

Note: I found references to a "Bluetooth logging" option under the bluetooth menu that would appear under the debug sub-menu when option-shift clicking the menu, but it seems that this option is no longer there as of 10.13

Answer (score 5):

Download the `Additional Tools for Xcode 9` from https://developer.apple.com/download/more/. In the Hardware folder there's an app called PacketLogger which is a Bluetooth packet logger.